# Remove unused classes in Qwik js

Tags: qwikjs

Qwik js is fast but for a big project with lot of css it's hard to manage. The problem is I need to remove unused classes. it should happen for only requested pages.

When I am requesting a page to server it should removed unused classes from the global css bundle atleast. If it remove extra unused classes from the module css then it would be very helpful.